# pull access denied for ybase_jdk, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login' for hybris-docker

Tags: docker, sap-commerce-cloud

```
➜  b2c_oms_dockerized ./build-images.sh
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.521MB
Step 1/8 : FROM ybase_jdk
pull access denied for ybase_jdk, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

I follow this tutorial

https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/56e101a9178544048ccf7aeb15780d83.html

to build a dockerized hybris.

I also logged in to my personal hub

```
➜  b2c_oms_dockerized docker login              
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username (asdasdsa): adsasda
Password: 
Login Succeeded
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pre install the prerequisite . Thats creating of base structure recipe followed by this.Make sure you have the base image installed, if not you can generate the default one following the description under /recipes/base_images/readme.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Remeber to add `sapjvm-8.1.035-linux-x64.rpm` at `installer/recipes/base_images/resourcess/base_jdk` and use `./install.sh -r base_images buildImages` instead of alternative route. It worked with 1808.

Also, do not forget additional images. Add them with `./install.sh -r base_images buildAdditionalImages`